# Installing proprietary NVidia driver on UEFI-loaded Ubuntu

Tags: 13.04, nvidia, uefi

I have installed Ubuntu using a Secure Boot option on UEFI. Since then I have disabled secure boot, and now I want to install NVidia drivers. But the *Additional Drivers* section of the Settings panel is still empty. How do I change that?

Comment: What video do you have? Are you running dual video? Post this:    lspci -nnk | grep -iA3 vga

Answer (score 1):

Installing `nvidia-current` manually worked. No doubt it will fail miserably if I ever reenable Secure Boot, though.

Comment: With secure boot enabled you would get a black screen  because no video driver is loaded (see [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/760780/nvidia-proprietary-driver-does-not-load-when-using-shimx64-since-xenial)).